# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable odoo8

Tags: function, odoo

on odoo 8 i try to  execute this action:

```
@api.onchange('projetbc_ligne_ids')
def onchange_evalID(self):
    self.test= self.projetbc_ligne_ids.produit.id
    query = "SELECT sum(quantite) FROM projet_bc_ligne where produit = %s"
    self.env.cr.execute(query, (tuple(self.projetbc_ligne_ids.produit.id),))
    # self.env.cr.execute("SELECT sum(quantite) FROM projet_bc_ligne where produit = %s",(tuple(self.projetbc_ligne_ids.produit.id),))
    self.projetbc_ids.quantite_encoure = self.env.cr.fetchone()[0]
```

i get this error :
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

your query is returning only one value so use self.env.cr.fetchone()
try this to know the type of you value :

```
print type(self.env.cr.fetchone())
```

if it's not `list` or `tuple` than you can not do self.env.cr.fetchone()[0]

> NB: you didn't show witch line cause the error so i'm thinking it's
>   fechtcheone[0]